# JSPM private registry configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jspm

I am using [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) to host a private package. I want to use this package in a project that I am working on locally. I have my package successfully published up to Verdaccio running on localhost (http://localhost:4873)

I am having trouble getting jspm to find this package when I run `jspm install`. I incremented the package version number when I published to verdaccio, and in my `package.json` of my local project I have also made the same version upgrade. My `~/.npmrc` file contains:

```
registry=https://npm.123-456.io
@myScope:registry=http://localhost:4873
```

I have tried using scoping here. I am using `jspm install` to install my packages. My `package.json` cotanins:

```
.
.
.
.
"jspm": {
"directories": {
  "baseURL": "src",
  "test": "test"
},
"configFile": "src/system.config.js",
"dependencies": {
  "myPackage": "npm:@myScope/myPackage@1.2.3",
  .
  .
  .
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install myPackage@1.2.3` (which is the version that is only contained on Verdaccio) it installs. However, `jspm install` results in the following:

```
err  Repo npm:@myScope/myPackage not found!
```

Do I need the scoping here? How can I make sure that when using `jspm install` that it actually finds my package hosted on Verdaccio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. When publishing the package, the `package.json` needed to contain the scope as well.

```
 "name": "@myScope/myPackage"
```

Simply publishing the package without the `@myScope` prefix, even with a new version number, was not enough for my project to locate the package from my private registry. The scope needed to be included.